# Limit of a function defined as an integral

Tags: limits

What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt$ ? I do not get any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Have you, as a random example, sketched what area this is asking for, for two or three small-ish choices of $x$?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Have _you_ tried to integrate $e^{-t^2}$? It turns out to be really difficult.

Comment: @Arthur it's impossible

Comment: Please read [this answer about refraining from asking  "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/9003)

Comment: Hint: for $x>0$, the quantity $\frac{1}{x}\int_{x}^{2x}e^{-t^2}\,dt$ is something between $e^{-x^2}$ and $e^{-(2x)^2}$. Not many chances if $x\to 0$ or $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: @Purushothman Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By l'Hospital

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\, (2e^{-(2x)^2}-e^{-x^2})$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINTS:**

For $t\in [x,2x]$ we have

$$e^{-t^2}\le e^{-x^2}$$

and $$\left|\int_a^{b}f(t)\,dt\right|\le \max_{t\in [a,b]}|f(t)| (b-a)$$

---

Alternatively, apply L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ F(x)=\int_0^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$$
then $$ F'(x) = e^{-x^2}$$ and

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{F(2x)-F(x)}{x}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(2F'(2x)-F'(x))=...$$